# Positioning a table for printing

Tags: templates, printing, html-table, position

Have a html-print I want to customize.
I need to print text in a certain position in the bottom of the page to fit a template (printed paper).
How can I position the last table exactly 2 inches from bottom? (the CartTable "belongs" to the application).
Right now the last table appears UNDER the CartTable.

Please help me!

---

```
<style>
    body
    {
        background-color:White;
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;    
    }
    .CartTable  {
        position:absolute;
        vertical-align:top; 
        padding-top:5pt; 
        width:492pt;
        border: 1px solid black;   
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;    }   .CartTable2     {
        position:absolute;
        vertical-align:top; 
        padding-top:5pt; 
        width:492pt;  
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;    }   .CartTdAmmount  {
       vertical-align:top; 
       text-align:right;        }   .BorderTopTable     {
        width:492pt;
        border-top: 3px solid black;   
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;    }   .BorderTable    {
        position:absolute;
        vertical-align:top; 
        padding-top:5pt; 
        width:498pt;
        border: 1px solid black;   
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;    }   .HeaderTr   {
        position:absolute;
        vertical-align:top;  
        padding-top:5pt;  
        border-bottom: solid 1px black; 
        background-color: #CCCCCC; 
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
        height:12pt;        } </style> <table class=##CartTable##>   <thead>##CartHeader## </thead> <tbody>##CartIncTax## </tbody> <tfoot> 
<tr> 
    <td colspan=7> 
      <table style="WIDTH: 492pt; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid">
        <tbody> 
        <tr style="HEIGHT: 18pt"> 
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody> 
      </table>
    </td>   </tr>   </tfoot>  </table>

<table>   <tr> 
    <td >&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Bankaccount info:</td>   </tr>   <tr> 
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td >##Bankaccount##</td>   </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like a [sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) would help ?

Comment: Thanks Francis but I cant get it to work...  SHould I instead work with positioning of my table? why does it appear at the same position as the CartTable?

Comment: Maybe a little html snippet would help, but I'd say it has something to do with the absolute positions. If you position an element (an image, a table or whatever) absolutely on your page, it will appear at the exact pixel specified, and the other content will ignore it in their presentation.